# python for loop effective and faster way

Tags: python, loops

```
ingredient_dic = {'SLS-Free': ['SLS'], 'SLES-Free':['SLES'], 'Parabens-Free': ['Parabens'],
                  'Formaldehydes-Free':['Formaldehydes'], 'Formaldehyde Releasers-Free':['Formaldehyde-Releasing Agents'],
                  'Phthalates-Free':['Phthalates'], 'Mineral Oil-Free':['Mineral-Oil','Mineral'],
                  'Retinyl Palmitate-Free':['Retinyl Palmitate'],'Oxybenzone-Free':['Oxybenzone'],
                 'Coal Tar-Free':['Coal Tar'], 'Hydroquinone-Free':['Hydroquinone'],
                 'Triclosan-Free':['Triclosan'],
                 'Triclocarban-Free':['Triclocarban']}

rev_ingredient_dic = {v:k for k, vs in ingredient_dic.items() for v in vs}
ing= ['Medium Coverage', 'Liquid Formula', 'Natural Finish', 'Long-wearing', 'allure 2018 Best of Beauty Award Winner', 'Community Favorite', 'Parabens']

lst = []
for key, value in rev_ingredient_dic.items():
    for element in ing:
        if key.lower() in element.lower():
            lst.append(value)
```

This works fine but it goes through multiple loops and I wonder if there is any better way to do this

Comment: Your code is clear and to the point, and does what you want. I guess you must be asking if this can't be be done in a slick one-line list comprehension. My answer would be Probably, but *please don't*.

Comment: @BoarGules why not, if the list comp is reasonably clear? It's concise and elegant. Not in all cases, but this one is ok imo.

Comment: Better *in what sense*? This question is not well-defined. What *exactly* is the problem you are trying to avoid with "multiple loops"?

Comment: @MaxShouman Elegance is of course in the eye of the beholder. But if OP needs help to figure out the one-liner then it is probably something they shouldn't be expecting to be able to read and understand in six months time.

Comment: "but it goes through multiple loops" In your own words, why do you expect this to be a problem?

Comment: I think it will become a problem as I have a bigger list. I guess a more clear question will be is there any way of achieving the same result without using the loop at all?

Comment: @Dan_Lee you *always* have to loop over your input, there's no way of beating the linear time dependency here, unless there is some property of your data we could exploit. Otherwise, a linear scan is the best you can do, there's no such thing as a free lunch

Comment: @Dan_Lee wait, are you referring to the list `ing`? If so, there *is* a better approach, which is *not to use a list at all* and use a `set`, which has constant-time look ups, instead of `linear` time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes the list ing can be bigger. So how do you suggest using `set` instead?

Comment: @Dan_Lee just make a `ing` a set rather than a list, and *make all the items lowercase to begin with*, then use `for key, value in rev_ingredient_dic.items(): if key.lower() in ing_set: ...` This *will* prevent linear scaling of the runtime on the size of `ing`

Comment: You also need to stop thinking in terms of "For loops are bad". Rather, you need to think in terms of "what data structures are appropriate for the task".

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [[val for element in ing if key.lower() in element.lower()] for key, val in rev_ingredient_dic.items()]

lst = [val for sublst in lst for val in sublst] # flattened
```

**EDITED** as the previous comprehension was wrong.

Comment: Although this is probably what OP intends, this is not identical to their code. Their code will append `value` possibly _multiple_ times (because there is no `continue`) whereas yours will only append it once due to `any`.

Comment: @BramVanroy That is true. Thanks for letting me notice, edited the answer.

Comment: Your edit doesn't actually fix this behavior pointed out by Bram, I don't think. In any case, there is a *direct transliteration*: `[val for key, val in rev_ingredient_dic.items() for element in ing if key.lower() in element.lower()]` but honestly, I'm not sure if this answers the question, which IMO is not well defined.

Comment: ALso, it's just plain wrong... any non-empty list is truthy, even one with `[False]` or `[False, False, False]`...

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga. The edit does not make a lot of sense since that list will always evaluate true.

Comment: `OutOfCoffeeError` on my side. I've double checked this one even if I'm not out of danger yet, so please bear with me. Thank you all btw for letting me correct this errors.